# geometry, angles between two lines

Tags: geometry

Two straight lines, AB and AD, lie in the same vertical plane. AB makes an angle of 25 degrees with the horizontal, and AD makes 32 degrees with the vertical. What is the angle between AB and AD?

The answer is 33 degrees or 97 degrees.

I cannot visualize what this question is asking. It says both AD and AD lie on the same vertical plane, then immediately says AD makes 32 degrees with the vertical. Isn't this a contradiction? Vertical plane means it has to be at a 90 degree angle with the horizontal plane. How is it possible for AD to make a 32 degree angle with the vertical if it is already on a vertical plane...

Comment: There is absolutely no contradiction. In any vertical *plane*, you find vertical, horizontal and oblique *lines*.

Comment: This has nothing to do with computers, computers don't know about geometry. Normal people do. Take a sheet of carton and knitting needles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch:

[image]
[image]
(Large versions: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fybYE.png) and [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA6sj.png))

Horizontal = $x$-axis
Vertical = $y$-axis

Comment: thanks ah i misread the question. "Vertical" and "vertical plane" are two different things. I confused them both as the plane.